# White mold or fungus on PT lumber

Tags: mold, lumber, pressure-treated, fungus

I'm building a wooden fence and have a number of 4x4 pressure treated lumber stacked neatly in my garage. I've been pulling posts from the stack as I work on the fence over the last 4 weeks. When I removed a post today, I noticed a white fungus or mold growing on the posts in the center of the stack. I didn't get a picture of it, but just scraped it off and sprayed the affected areas with a 10% bleach solution.

Now that I'm thinking about it I'm concerned the posts may be defective. **Should pressure treated lumber support fungus or mold growth?**

Comment: Keep in mind, the industry is really scraping the bottom of the barrel for PT wood.  Apparently with all the COVID lockdowns, everyone's building decks lol. So you may have gotten leftovers to begin with.  If this happened in your storage, it's time to learn to stack wood :)

Comment: Agreed, Harp. Most building wood, esp. PT which usually has a very high moisture content should be stacked with stickers between the boards vertically and a half inch - inch or so between them horizontally to allow for air flow. Also best to store high moisture content wood outside, but covered only on top (like a wood shed).

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson The posts are quite heavy with moisture content. I assumed because they are PT and came bundled without being stickered that they did not need to be stickered. It would help future me if you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most building wood, esp. PT which usually has a very high moisture content should be stacked with stickers between the boards vertically and a half inch - inch or so between them horizontally to allow for air flow. Also best to store high moisture content wood outside, but covered only on top (like a wood shed). (posted as an answer at the request of the OP).